# In Cordova/Phonegap/Webpack application: Uncaught ReferenceError: argscheck is not defined

Tags: cordova, typescript, webpack, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I am building a phonegap application which I created using

`phonegap create MyApp --template blank`

and then later added Webpack to build Typescript sources into the `www` directory.

I'm now trying to use the `Media` plugin which I added using the command

`phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-media`

I am attempting to use this from my Typescript sources by importing

`import * as Media from 'cordova-plugin-media/www/Media';`

and then using

```
test() {
    var sound = new Media('cdvfile://localhost/www/woopwoop.mp3', ()=>{});
    sound.play();
}
```

when the application runs, it errors out:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: argscheck is not defined
    at Object.cordova/argscheck (argscheck":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../node_modules/cordova-plugin-media/www/Media.js (Media.js:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

This is happening because the newly added Media plugin contains:

```
var argscheck = require('cordova/argscheck'),
    utils = require('cordova/utils'),
    exec = require('cordova/exec');
```

and therefore webpack tries to resolve these require statements.

I have determined that the `argscheck` is a piece that's defined within the `cordova.js` file which phonegap is generating and serving up, in Chrome I can see that `cordova.js` contains:

```
// file: src/common/argscheck.js
define("cordova/argscheck", function(require, exports, module) {
```

But since webpack is not processing this as one of the sources, webpack does not know how to resolve the import.

Given that `cordova.js` seems to be a built file itself, and how do I get webpack to be aware of its contents so that the plugin import and its dependencies can be resolved?

Comment: It's not exactly an answer to my own question, but I did find that I could get the functionality I need simply by using html <audio> tags instead of using the media plugin.  Initially I thought this would have limitations, e.g. I wanted to have an alarm sound which would be audible even if the app was not the current focused app (in Android) and assumed that the media plugin might be the only way to achieve that, but the <audio> tag does play even when the app is not focused, so I don't think I have any need for the media plugin.

Comment: I remember seeing this error also when trying to get a plugin to work.  I honestly can't remember how I got it to work but it might have been because I was trying to call the plugin before the device was ready.  Or maybe it worked when I manually added the `cordova.js` files to the `www/` folder directly...